How to increase current by reducing voltage?
I have a 400kv HV generator of 500 mA , but I want to increase the current by 10 time or more by reducing less voltage as possible/sufficient , help

What operating frequency is the output?

400 kV and 500 mA is 200 kW, and at that high power a modification to increase current while lowering the voltage may be non-trivial. To help get an answer can you edit the question to include a link to information on the HV generator.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your question reads like any answerer needs a lot of liability insurance. Without lots more detail, it seems you might set fire to your house or electrocute yourself.

The power you specify - 200kW - would serve 10-20 homes, a small apartment complex or a medium-sized light industrial building.
If your power is 400kV AC, you would use a 10:1 step-down transformer to take your feed down to 40kV and 5A. Because of the voltages involved this needs to be in a secure enclosure, so the task is much more involved than just specifying the transformer.
If your power is 400kV DC, you would be consulting with a supplier like ABB or Siemens for this specialty DC-AC gear in addition to the secure enclosure, again to make 40kV AC.
In reality the costs associated with such a high voltage make it not economically viable at just 200kW. Usually such systems supply tens to hundreds of MW to metro-sized grids. In comparison, 200kW would be one neighborhood transformer being fed by a medium range voltage, 12kV - 25kV or so.

tens to hundreds of mW - so 0.01W - 0.1W?

Fixed. Blame autocarrot.
